# How to make a popup onClick with hability to enter text inside and send the content to another page?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap CSS and I have a form with glyphicons next to each person.

Like that : [image]

I would like when I click on the Tag glyphicons it popups something like that : 
[image]

The visitor write something inside it and press **OK** then it goes to another page for UPDATE the note from Alexis.

How can we do a similar popups and when pressing **OK** it is like an `<a href=mysite?somevalues:somevalues">OK</a>` ?

Comment: bootstrap has a modal dialog. you can use it to display a popup like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try something like this:

Click this link for more details: - 
http://www.bootply.com/X4oaJWOzOi

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">LName FNmae</span>

</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Note</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
<label for="comment">Comment:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```